# Waiting for all child processes to be created - C

Tags: c, process, parent, wait

Let's suppose I have a code like the following

```
    switch (fork()) {
      case -1:
          //error checking
          break; 
      case 0:
          //child code
          break;
      default:
          int i;
          for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
              switch (fork()) {
                  case -1:
                      //error checking
                      break; 
                  case 0:
                      //exec
                      break;
                  default:
                      //parent that waits for all childs to be created
                      break; 
              }
         }
    }
```

How do I make the second parent process wait for all the other processes to be created exactly ...
I was told I had to make a loop but I don't know how to implement it exactly. Supposing there are n child processes.

Comment: What do you mean by wait for all childs. The parent creates each process as needed by the loop - when the loop has finished it has created them all. So what is you question?

Comment: What you are looking for is a synchronization barrier. see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1601/gfwek.html for example.

Comment: What do you mean by the second parent there is only one parent and n+1 child.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have misunderstood the requirement slightly.  The term 'second parent' doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

What makes most sense as a requirement is:

- Parent process launches N children.
- Each child does its appropriate stuff.
- The parent process must then wait for all N children to complete.
- Then it can report its own completion (or get on with other work, or ...).

In outline, you would then have:

```
int pid;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    switch (pid = fork())
    {
    case 0:
        be_childish(i);
        /*NOTREACHED*/
        break;
    case -1:
        // Print error report
        break;
    default:
        printf("Started PID %d\n", pid);
        break;
    }
}

int status;
while ((pid = wait(&status)) > 0)
{
    printf("PID %d exited (status 0x%.4X)\n", pid, status);
}

printf("All done!\n");
```

Note the `/*NOTREACHED*/` comment.  I assume that the child process exits from within the `be_childish()` function.  The code could ensure no damage by including an `exit(1);` or perhaps `_exit(1);` or `_Exit(1);`.  It is rather important that a child process does not continue the loop.